# Check which elements of a vector is between the elements of another one in R

Tags: r

I am new user in R. How can I check which elements of the vector `A` is between the elements of vector `B` for example:

```
    A = c(1.1, 3.2, 5, 8.5, 4.6, 2.2)
    B = c(1, 2, 3)
```

means that which elements of `A` is between 1 and 2 , then which elemets of `A` is between 2 and 3?

Comment: what is expected output? a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want some variant of `findInterval`

```
findInterval(A,B)
[1] 1 3 3 3 3 2
```

Value 1 indicates it is between 1 and 2 (the lowest and next lowest value in B)
Value 2 indicates it is between 2 and 3

So to find which ones are between

```
which(findInterval(A,B) %in% seq_len(length(unique(B))-1))
# [1] 1 6
```

and to extract from `A`

```
A[findInterval(A,B) %in% seq_len(length(unique(B))-1)]

# [1] 1.1 2.2
```

You could also use `cut`, which will create a factor.

In conjunction with `split` this will give

```
 split(A, cut(A,B),drop=FALSE)
$`(1,2]`
[1] 1.1

$`(2,3]`
[1] 2.2
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get seperately the result means for the first interval and second seperately, not in one vector and also I should mentioned that vector B may not be consecutive numebrs.

Comment: @rose -- please make a reproducible example of what you want, I've added another possibility, Do you really want the separate vectors? Find interval doesn't require consecutive numbers, but sorted non decreasingly numbers, cut requires unique breaks.

Comment: Nice approach.  It escaped me but seems perfectly obvious now :) +1

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly this is one possibility:

```
A = c(1.1, 3.2, 5, 8.5, 4.6, 2.2)
B = c(1, 2, 3,4,10)

B1 <- head(B, -1)
B2 <- tail(B, -1)

outs <- list()

for(i in seq_along(B1)) {
    outs[[i]] <- A[B1[i] < A & A < B2[i]]
}

names(outs) <- paste(B1, " & ", B2)

## > outs
## $`1  &  2`
## [1] 1.1
## 
## $`2  &  3`
## [1] 2.2
## 
## $`3  &  4`
## [1] 3.2
## 
## $`4  &  10`
## [1] 5.0 8.5 4.6
```

Comment: I realized that after seeing your response :)  Likely mine is not as fast.

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that it is going to be consecutive numbers in B for which you will be checking

```
result.pair<-matrix(rep(integer(), 3), ncol = 3)
colnames(result.pair)<-c("B1", "A", "B2")
for(i in 1:(length(B)))
{
  for(j in 1:(length(A)))
  {
    if ((B[i] <= A[j])  & (B[i+1] >= A[j]))
    {
      result.pair<-rbind(result.pair, c(B[i], A[j], B[i+1]))
    }
  }

}

result.pair
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
      data.frame(A,cut(A,B))
```

For each observation in A, it tells you which pair of B observations it's between.

Like so:

```
> data.frame(A,cut(A,B))
    A cut.A..B.
1 1.1     (1,2]
2 3.2      <NA>
3 5.0      <NA>
4 8.5      <NA>
5 4.6      <NA>
6 2.2     (2,3]
```

NA means it isn't between two B observations.

Also try:

```
data.frame(A,cut(A,c(-Inf,B,Inf)))
```