# Is between two elements in R

Tags: r

I want to check the elements of the vector

```
   a = c(0.15, 1.5, 11, 15, 22)
```

is between the elements of the vector

```
    b =c(0, 3, 5, 10, 20, 25)
```

which means that is the second element of vector `a` between the second and third elements of the vector `b` or not, ... but not checkig the first element of `a`.

How can I do it in R?

Comment: How is this different to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15802278/check-which-elements-of-a-vector-is-between-the-elements-of-another-one-in-r?

Comment: The length of vector a is just one unit less than vector b and I do not want to use split.

Comment: @rose, it looks like you may be having some legitimate difficulties adapting the solutions provided to fit your needs.  There are plenty of amazing free resources that give quick introductions to working with R objects, indexing etc.  they might be worth a read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives what you want:

```
larger <- a[1:length(a)] > b[1:(length(b)-1)]
smaller <- a[1:length(a)] < b[2:length(b)]
between <- larger & smaller
between[1] <- FALSE
a[between]
```

First you check whether or not the elements in a are smaller than the corresponding elements in b. Then you select if they are smaller than the next element in b. Combine both and remoe the unwanted first. Tada.